# Problem with decision variabile when there are more choices

Tags: variables, cplex

I have a series of jobs. For each job I have a series of operations and each operation requires a machine. But there are some operations that have the ability to choose multiple machines.

Ex:

job 1:     operation 1 machine 4
operation 2 machine 2
operation 3 (machine 2 or machine 3)

I have a binary decision variable Y (ijm) where i is the operation, j the job and m the machine.

What must happen is that Y(114) = 1, Y (212) = 1 but for operation 3 we have two choices Y(312) = 0 and Y(313) = 1 or the opposite.

How can I implement it on Cplex? I can't find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a logical constraint like this in OPL:

```
((x==2) && (y==1)) || ((x==1) && (y==2));
```

But you could also have a look at [CPOptimizer](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=programming-scheduling-examples) within CPLEX because your model looks like a scheduling problem.

Comment: If I write dvar boolean y[I][J][M] and when I write y[1][1][1] == 1; CPLEX gives me error: "syntax error, unexpected (integer-literal)"

Comment: Can you open a new question with the model that does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to model your requirement that Y(312) = 0 and Y(313) = 1 or the opposite would be to add a constraint that the sum of the alternatives must be 1, i.e. in your case add a constraint:

Y(312) + Y(313) = 1

Then if the variables are binary or integer then this will achieve your aim.